# Javascript str.search() multiple instances

Tags: javascript, string, search, indexing, multiple-instances

How can I retrieve multiple indexes from multiple instances of a string search?

```
var str = "food";
var index1 = str.search("o"); // 1
var index2 = str.search("o"); // ?
```

Thanks much,
Wen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use second parameter of `indexOf` method to achieve what you want:

```
var str = "food",
    index1 = str.indexOf("o"),
    index2 = str.indexOf("o", index1+1);
```

Answer (score 15):

I think the best way to do this for strings of non-trivial length is the [`RegExp.exec()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var str = "Foooooooood!",
    re = /o/g,
    match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match.index); // logs 1 through 9
}
```