# Using a Regex to insert a / at the end of an img tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to insert an ending slash before the closing bracket of every `img` tag found in a string.

This (modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825492/javascript-str-search-multiple-instances)) is correctly returning the position of each instance of `img`:

```
var re = /img\s/g,
    match;
    while (match = re.exec(str)) {
      console.log(match.index); //
    }
```

Knowing this, how can I find the next > after each `img`and insert a / before it?

Comment: Why would you need it ?

Comment: Because I am passing the HTML string to a PHP application that wants XHTML, not HTML, and it's breaking on the img tags because they are unclosed.

Comment: Additionally: Yes, I am extremely sure that img tags will be the only self-closing tags that will ever appear in the string in question.

Comment: It seems you never learn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Oh FFS. The second answer on that question specifies the occasional usefulness of regex with limited, known HTML.

Comment: For what it's worth, `<img>` is a "void element" and doesn't need a closure: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

Comment: I know, and for display purposes I wouldn't ever close it, but it needs to act like XHTML for this particular period of its lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
var imgs = "<img blblblb > <img adadasd>"
var pattern = /(<img[^>]*)>/g;

imgs = imgs.replace(pattern, "$1/>");
console.log(imgs);
//<img blblblb /> <img adadasd/>
```

Comment: Accepted because I saw it first, and it worked first time. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

How about this, it's simple but seems like it would work for your case:

```
str.replace(/(<img[^>]*)>/g, "$1 />");
```

if you wanted it to be a little more smart, you could do something like this:

```
str.replace(/(<img[^>]*?) *\/?>/g, "$1 />");
```

[**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UhQa/) would account for things that already have a space and/or a slash at the end... and create the same output for all of the following:

```
IN:
<img src='foo.png'>
<img src='foo.png' >
<img src='foo.png'/>
<img src='foo.png' />
OUT for all the above:
<img src='foo.png' />
```

if you would rather have `<img src='foo.png'/>`, just remove the space after `$1` in the replace.

Answer (score 1):

I have a non-regex solution, if you’re interested:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function close_img_tags(){
var str = document.getElementById("txt").value, len = str.length, i, j;
for(i = 0; i < len-4; i++){
    if(str[i]+str[i+1]+str[i+2]+str[i+3] == "<img"){
        for(j = i+4; j < len; j++){
            if(str[j] == ">"){
                if(str[j-1] != "/"){
                str = str.substr(0, j)+"/"+str.substr(j);
                i = j+2;
                }
                else{
                i = j+1;
                }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("txt").value = str;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
textarea{
width:400px;
height:300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea><br/>
<button type="button" onclick="close_img_tags();">Edit HTML</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eZu9U/